# C# Type system support to express types that matches constraints

Tags: c#

The problem:

```
public class Test
{
    public void A<T>(T arg)
    {
        // We have proof it's safe to call B
        if (arg is IEquatable<T>)
        {
            // To call B, something like this needed.
            // var arg1 = (T:IEquatable<T>) arg;
            // B(arg1)

            B(arg); // Error CS0314: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Test.B<T>(T)'.
                    // There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IEquatable<T>'.
        }
        else
        {
            C(arg);
        }
    }

    public void B<T>(T arg)
        where T: IEquatable<T>
    {
        // We don't want to loos the original type T that has been passed to A<T>
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public void C<T>(T arg)
    {
    }
}
```

Do we have any C# language constructs that allows to call more generic method with more restrictions on type, if we have proofs it's safe (Higher Kinder Polymorphism, advanced pattern matching, etc) ?

Do we have any option to make a weird unsafe hack to make unallowed generic method call ?
Looks like we can express the call on IL level (Fody + https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/InlineIL.Fody) or somehow Function Pointers can be used.
(Sure reflection can help, but it's expensive and might cause an issues with the CoreRT native compilation).

Comment: So you're passing `arg` with type `T` and you test it if it is an `IEquatable<T>` in `if (arg is IEquatable<T>)` ?

Comment: You get a similar error message with the slightly simpler `if (arg is IEquatable<T> barg) { B(barg); }`  I have no idea why: `Error CS0311 The type 'System.IEquatable<T>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TestGeneric.B<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.IEquatable<T>' to 'System.IEquatable<System.IEquatable<T>>`

Comment: Change `if (arg is IEquatable<T>)` to `if (arg is IEquatable<T> arg2)` and change `B(arg)` to `B(arg2)` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a type constraint what if your parameter type would be `IEquatable<T>`?

You don't know anything else about that `T` type so it isn't worth using it as the parameter type instead of `IEquatable<T>` type.

```cs
class Test
{
    public void A<T>(T arg)
    {
        if (arg is IEquatable<T> equatable)
        {
            B1(equatable);
        }
        else
        {
            C(arg);
        }

        B1(2);
        B2(2);
    }

    public void B1<T>(IEquatable<T> arg)
    {
        // This should write the original type T that has been passed to A<T>
        // because if a type implements IEquatable<>
        // then the type parameter should be the same as the implementing type.
        // Just what your type constraint expects, anyway.
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);

        // But you can also get the real T type by using .GetType() method.
        Console.WriteLine(arg.GetType());

        // Should output true.
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T) == arg.GetType());
    }

    // You can keep this method as an overload,
    // if you really need it for some reason.
    public void B2<T>(T arg) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        B1(arg);
    }

    public void C<T>(T arg)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> To call B, something like this needed.
>
> ```cs
> var arg1 = (T:IEquatable<T>) arg
> ```

Yes, that is the core of the problem. And no, such a language feature doesn't exist.

To call `B1` as is, you need to structure you solution so that the caller can provide a type that matches its signature. The only alternative is reflection.

So your choices are either to relax the constraints of `B1`. Perhaps by moving the implementation to a new private method which is easier to call from `A`. Or overload `A<T>` so the caller can prove that `T:IEquatable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/905